# Append File Chunks to a 2GB File Using PHP

Tags: php, file-io, append, 32-bit, chunks

I am using the Resumable.js library to upload files in 1 MB chunks and then piecing them back together using PHP on a 32-bit linux server (PHP 5.3.14, Apache 2.0)

This is working great, except for with files over 2GB.

When I upload a file that is larger than 2GB, it appears to work fine, but when you actually view the file properties the size is always 2147483648 bytes.

From my reading, I understand this to be a limitation of PHP's use of 32-bit integers.

I have read that setting the CFLAGS="-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" flag and recompiling PHP will allow PHP to open files larger than 2GB.

My question is, if I do this, will this fix my problem, or is the opening of the file not just the problem, but the appending of the file as well?

If this will fix my 2GB problem, is there still a (higher) theoretical max file size?

If I'm completely off base and this flag will not fix my problems, are there any other potential solutions besides switching to a 64-bit server?

Comment: Which file system? usually PHP doesn't have problems with large files (even if I would _always_ recommend you to use a 64bit system), thus I guess it's a limitation of the used filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stuck at the 2GB file size limit by Linux on 32-bit machines (see http://linuxmafia.com/faq/VALinux-kb/2gb-filesize-limit.html ).

You might want to consider keeping the total file split into chunks of some smaller size, or get a 64 bit machine. Typically files larger than a GB are avoided in many systems over chunk implementations anyway for performance purposes.

Comment: Hmmm...well, I am able to upload files larger than 2GB via FTP....

Sorry, I guess I was assuming the Linux OS is 32-bit based on the fact that I know a 32-bit version of PHP is installed.

I will have to have my client verify with his shared hosting if it is 32-bit or 64-bit.

By the fact that I can upload files larger than 2GB via FTP, would that seem to indicate that I have a 64-bit OS with a 32-bit version of PHP installed?

Comment: That's very possible -- I had that issue with a Redhat server once which came with 32bit versions of a lot of software even though the machine was 64bit.

Comment: Still waiting to find out if the server is 32-bit or 64-bit for sure, but lets assume for a min that it is 64-bit OS (since I can upload larger than 2GB files via FTP) with a 32-bit version of PHP. Do you think setting the CFLAGS="-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" flag and recompiling PHP would fix my problem, or would I still need to install the 64-bit version of PHP?

Comment: You could try recompiling if it's fast and easy to test, but it would probably be cleaner to just reinstall a 64bit version.

Comment: @user1555774 Could you please give an update if this didn't answer your question or accept an answer?

Comment: sorry, I'm still waiting to hear back from my client.  I'll go ahead and accept the answer though, thanks so much for the info!